# Apollo Graphql Server: Request takes a full minute to reach resolver

Tags: performance, express, graphql, apollo-server

I am using Apollo Graphql on a NodeJS server. I recently notices that my requests were taking a lot of time and decided to get into the issue. I added log timestamp and added console logs to various locations in my server to figure out the bottleneck. My server code is as follows:

```
(async function () {
  
  const app = express();
  const httpServer = createServer(app);

  const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    server: httpServer,
    path: "/graphql",
  });
  const serverCleanup = useServer({ schema }, wsServer);

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    plugins: [
      ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
      {
        async serverWillStart() {
          return {
            async drainServer() {
              await serverCleanup.dispose();
            },
          };
        },
      },
      myPlugin
    ],
    healthCheckPath: '/health',
    async onHealthCheck() {
      return
    },
  });


  await server.start();

  app.use(
    '/',
    cors(),
    // 50mb is the limit that `startStandaloneServer` uses, but you may configure this to suit your needs
    bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }),
    // expressMiddleware accepts the same arguments:
    // an Apollo Server instance and optional configuration options
    expressMiddleware(server, {
      context: async ({ req }) => {
        let decodedToken
        try {
          if (env === 'development') {
            decodedToken = {
              uid: "test"
            }
          } else {
            decodedToken = await verifyIdToken(req.headers?.authorization?.replace('Bearer ', ''))
          }
        } catch (error) {
          decodedToken = null
        }
        return {
          decodedToken,
          jwt: decodedToken
        }
      }
    }),
  );

  await new Promise((resolve) => httpServer.listen({ port: 4000 }, resolve));
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000/`);

})()
```

Then in my graphql resolvers I have code similar to this

```
const { AuthenticationError } = require('@apollo/server/express4');
const mutations = {
   createPost: async(_, { createPostInput }, context) => {
        console.log('In graphql mutation')
        if (!context.decodedToken || !Object.keys(context.decodedToken).length) {
            throw new AuthenticationError('Unauthenticated');
        }
        console.log('In graphql mutation 2')
        return await createPostApi(createPostInput);
   }
}
```

code for "my plugin" passed to apollo server is taken from apollo docs. It only prints logs for various events.

```
const myPlugin = {
    // Fires whenever a GraphQL request is received from a client.
    async requestDidStart(requestContext) {
      console.log('Request started!');

      return {
        // Fires whenever Apollo Server will parse a GraphQL
        // request to create its associated document AST.
        async parsingDidStart(requestContext) {
          console.log('Parsing started!');
        },

        // Fires whenever Apollo Server will validate a
        // request's document AST against your GraphQL schema.
        async validationDidStart(requestContext) {
          console.log('Validation started!');
        },

        async executionDidStart(requestContext) {
          console.log('Execution started!');
        },
      };
    },
  };
```

I have installed log-timestamp package to print timestamp for each log and here is the output

```
[2023-01-31T18:23:02.428Z] Request started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:02.430Z] Parsing started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:02.432Z] Validation started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:02.450Z] Execution started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:03.081Z] Request started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:03.081Z] Parsing started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:03.081Z] Validation started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:03.083Z] Execution started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:03.380Z] Request started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:03.381Z] Execution started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:18.290Z] Request started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:18.291Z] Execution started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:22.878Z] Request started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:22.878Z] Execution started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:23.878Z] Request started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:23.878Z] Execution started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:24.869Z] Request started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:24.869Z] Execution started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:30.389Z] Request started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:30.390Z] Execution started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:41.372Z] Request started!
[2023-01-31T18:23:41.373Z] Execution started!
[2023-01-31T18:24:01.046Z] Request started!
[2023-01-31T18:24:01.047Z] Execution started!
[2023-01-31T18:24:02.040Z] Request started!
[2023-01-31T18:24:02.041Z] Execution started!
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.180Z] In graphql mutation
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.180Z] In graphql mutation 2
// logs below this point are from my actual mutation. Actual log output has been redacted
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.180Z] Starting ...
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.181Z] Inside function
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.181Z] Sorting ...
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.181Z] Getting from db ...
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.311Z] Got ...
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.311Z] Creating ... input
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.312Z] Creating ... input
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.312Z] Creating ... Input
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.312Z] Creating in db
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.702Z] Fetching fetching from db
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.756Z] parsing
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.756Z] Starting another thing
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.756Z] In that other thing
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.756Z] Starting a third thing
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.760Z] Creating (db call) ...
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.803Z] Finding (db call) ...
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.836Z] Creating (another db call) ...
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.838Z] Creating (db call) ...
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.838Z] Creating (db call) ...
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.839Z] Creating (db call)...
[2023-01-31T18:24:03.840Z] Finishing ...
```

As you can see, the request started at **18:23:02** and reached the resolver at **18:24:03**, a **full minute later**. There is no middleware involved, this is my local machine so there is no network latency issue or wait for token verification either. The actual business logic gets executed within the same second but overall time becomes 1min+. How can I reduce this lag?

Comment: Interesting problem! My queries typically execute in milliseconds (locally) or 10-100 ms on AWS so a minute is wildly out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly enough, a simple machine restart fixed the problem. Although I still do not understand what caused this in the first place. Could be a problem related to MacOS or Apollo server.